# How to get data where ImageField in not null in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

context_processor.py file

```
    def context_processor(request):
    context={}
    context['services'] = Services.objects.filter(bg_image__isnull=False)
    return context
```

models.py

```
class Services(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    bg_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='services/', null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have 7 record where 5 of them has bg_image rest of 2 bg_image are null. when I query the above code show 7 record has bg_image. who can I query property to get only those records where bg_image is not null? For queryset when I use within bracket active=True it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Services.objects.exclude(bg_image='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this exclude instead

```
def context_processor(request):
    context={}
    context['services'] = Services.objects.filter().exclude(big_image=None)
    return context
```